# Will using a microSD card reader with STM32 produce logical errors?

Tags: sd, logic-level

I have a microSD card reader which needs \$5\,\mathrm{V}\$ to operate.
I am interfacing it with STM32 MCU operating at \$3.3\,\mathrm{V}\$.

Will it operate normally when I provide only \$3.3\,\mathrm{V}\$?

Presently, I do not have \$5\,\mathrm{V}\$ to supply to the card reader but only \$3.3\,\mathrm{V}\$.

[Datasheet](http://datalogger.pbworks.com/w/file/fetch/89507207/Datalogger%20-%20SD%20Memory%20Reader%20Datasheet.pdf) link is here.
[image]

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Comment: microSD card adapters are typically passive devices which operate at whatever voltage is supplied by whatever system you plug them into.

Comment: please be clear in your question. or, you can draw a setup(post an image)  to explain it better

Comment: Please clarify what you mean be "microSD card adapter" - is it one of these? https://hobbycomponents.com/adapters/578-microsd-card-adapter-with-level-shifters

Comment: Still unanswerable without documentation of the **exact** circuitry on board.  But you don't need that, it would be simpler to just use a passive breakout.

Comment: answer below three questions: 1. are you supplying 5 V to the card adapter?, 2. are you running STM32 at 3.3 V, 3. are you planning to use 3.3 V for both adapter and connector?

Comment: I am not supplying 5v to card adapter but use 3.3v for both adapter and connector . yes I am running stm32 at 3.3v@Umar

Comment: I am seeing this question being edited for a purpose from many days. Here it is. it will not work with your current setup. The card reader has a 3.3 V regualtor on board. you have to supply 5 V for the regulator (the IC with name U and three pins on one side and a big tab on the other side). You can make it work though. you can bypass the regulator and provide 3.3 V directly at the output pin. You have to Rework the PCB though. The regulator most probably is AMS1117 (based on other images from internet, consider it with a grain of salt)

Comment: Thanks .But why the regulator doesn't work at 3.3v .

Comment: Read up on the issue of regulator `dropout voltage`

Comment: I see there's an LDO on the board. if you remove it and manage to short the input with the output you can work it at 3.3V

Answer (score 4):

> microSD card adapter operates at 5v when connecting to 3.3v of stm32

No, it doesn't. An SD to microSD card adapter is purely a physical adapter -- there is no level shifting involved. SD and microSD cards both operate at a maximum of 3.3V.

[image]

([source](https://www.camerahacker.com/Digital/Inside_miniSD_Adapter.shtml))